# Replacing NSString with new string not working

Tags: objective-c, cocos2d-iphone, cocos2d-iphone-3

I'm trying to replace a string every second by using a timer to update its value. Normally I can replace an NSString pretty easily by doing

`myString = [CCLabelTTF labelWithString:varyingParameterLabelString fontName:@"Helvetica" fontSize:14];`

for example, but for some reason it won't update my NSString's value. Below is what I'm trying to do.

```
@implementation Grid
{
    NSTimer *timeRemainingTimer;
    CCLabelTTF *_varyingParameterLabelValue;
}


-(void)setupLabels{
    int timeRemaining = 30;
    varyingParameterLabelValueString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i", timeRemaining];
    timeRemainingTimer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:1.0 target:self selector:@selector(decreaseTimeRemaining) userInfo:nil repeats:TRUE];
    _varyingParameterLabelValue = [CCLabelTTF labelWithString:varyingParameterLabelValueString fontName:@"Helvetica" fontSize:20];
[self addChild:_varyingParameterLabelValue];
}


-(void)decreaseTimeRemaining{
    timeRemaining--;
    NSString *timeRemainingString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i", timeRemaining];
    _varyingParameterLabelValue = [CCLabelTTF labelWithString:@"timeRemainingString" fontName:@"Helvetica" fontSize:20];
//Still reads 30 after this runs
}
```

If I literally just copy and paste the last line of my timer method into the setupLabels method, it changes the string like normal, but inside of the timer method it doesn't do anything. I have logged to make sure the timer is running, and it definitely is. Thanks for the help!

Comment: It's unclear what you mean by "it doesn't like my code". Can you give more details?

Comment: Sorry if that was misleading, I meant that it just isn't updating the NSString

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In `decreaseTimeRemaining` you create a local variable called `timeRemainingString`, but then you never use it to update the label.  Also, you are creating a whole new label instead of updating the existing one.

```
-(void)decreaseTimeRemaining{
    timeRemaining--;
    NSString *timeRemainingString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i", timeRemaining];
    [_varyingParameterLabelValue setString:timeRemainingString];
}
```

Comment: Yeah, I was just using that as a check. It doesn't even update to the 25 though, and if I do put in the timeRemainingString, it also does not update, I edited it now

Comment: Using the code you gave me, it gives me and error "Property 'varyingParameterLabelValue' not found on object of type 'My Class *'"...even though I clearly added it to "self."

Comment: Like I said, if I copy and pasted my original code into the top method, it works. But for some reason in the other method run by the timer, it doesn't...

Comment: So, what is `_varyingParameterLabelValue` and what is it a property of?  Where is this variable declared?

Comment: It is declared in the implementation section of my class, named 'Grid'. When I use 'self', then, it refers to 'Grid'.

Comment: Can you show the line of code that declares the variable?

Comment: updated, I included a little more info too. I can't seem to update the value anywhere except locally within the method where it is first given a value for the String